# python print text node value in xml element

Tags: python, xml, dom, nodevalue

EDIT:

Thank you guys, I completely forgot the : at the end of the for statement. Also, for the original tags that I had with the spaces, I was just using that as filler text! The actual names do have aword_anotherword as element tags

Now if I have something like this,

```
<TIER name="a">
<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> a1</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>

<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> a2</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>

<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> a3</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>
</TIER>

<TIER name="b">
<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> b1</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>

<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> b2</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>

<tier_1> 
 <tier_2>
   <tier_3> b3</tier_3> 
 </tier_2>
</tier_1>
</TIER>
```

How would I go abot printing just the tier_3 from the first tier with name="a" ?

---

---

---

I have an xml sheet something like this

```
<ALL TIERS>
<tier 1> 
 <tier 2>
   <tier 3> Hello one!</tier3> 
 </tier 2>
</tier 1>

<tier 1> 
 <tier 2>
   <tier 3> Hello two!</tier3> 
 </tier 2>
</tier 1>

<tier 1> 
 <tier 2>
   <tier 3> Hello three!</tier3> 
 </tier 2>
</tier 1>

</ALL TIERS>
```

I want to print allo f tier 3's text node values, using python so it turns ut like this

Hello one! Hello two! Hello three!

I wrote this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom 
xmldoc = minidom.parse(sys.argv[1])
xlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('tier 3') 

for i in xlist

    print " ".join(t.nodeValue for t in i.childNodes if t.nodeType==t.TEXT_NODE)
```

but that gives me an error of invalid syntax pointing to "for i in xlist"

ccould someone help me correct this?
Thank you!

Comment: `for i in xlist` should be `for i in xlist:` Please do take the initiative to review the Python documentation. It really is excellent, and a lot of good people have put a lot of effort into creating it for you.

Comment: oh dear I completely forgot about that... thank you!! I will read more into it!

Comment: This is not valid XML: `<ALL TIERS>` Is this really your document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you're missing the `:` on the for statement

```
for i in xlist:
```

You're also going to want to `import sys` and your XML isn't well formed, maybe use `<ALL_TIERS>` instead of `<ALL TIERS>`? (You'd want to change the closing tags as well.)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to get the `text` from you Xml.

Also your Xml isn't well formed as the tags have <kbd>spaces</kbd> in them.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
txt = """<ALL-TIERS>
<tier-1>
 <tier-2>
   <tier-3> Hello one!</tier-3>
 </tier-2>
</tier-1>
<tier-1>
 <tier-2>
   <tier-3> Hello two!</tier-3>
 </tier-2>
</tier-1>
<tier-1>
 <tier-2>
   <tier-3> Hello three!</tier-3>
 </tier-2>
</tier-1>
</ALL-TIERS>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(txt)

for e in root.iter('ALL-TIERS'):
    print ">>"
    print ET.tostring(e, method="text").strip()
    print "<<"

for e in root.iter('tier-3'):
    print ">>"
    print ET.tostring(e, method="text").strip()
    print "<<"
```

Gives:

```
>>
Hello one!




    Hello two!




    Hello three!
<<
>>
Hello one!
<<
>>
Hello two!
<<
>>
Hello three!
<<
```

Comment: oh hm I think you answered my edited question. Thank you!